Token swap error 0x26 InvalidSplTokenProgram raydium-sdk-V2-demo
I am trying to execute a token swap on Solana using the Raydium SDK and GPT, but I keep encountering an error when I attempt to send the transaction. The error is related to the InvalidSplTokenProgram, and the simulation fails with the following log output:
SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x26.
Logs:
[ 
  "Program routeUGWgWzqBWFcrCfv8tritsqukccJPu3q5GPP3xS invoke [1]",
  "Program log: process_swap_base_in_with_user_account:RouteSwapBaseInArgs { amount_in: 10000000, minimum_amount_out: 11756 }",
  "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Error: InvalidSplTokenProgram",
  "Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: custom program error: 0x26",
  "Program routeUGWgWzqBWFcrCfv8tritsqukccJPu3q5GPP3xS failed: custom program error: 0x26"
]


Steps I took:

I configured the swap input and output mint addresses (SOL to token).
I requested data from the swap service and pool service successfully, receiving the     expected route and pool data.
I created the transaction and added the swap instruction using the Raydium SDK function swapBaseInAutoAccount().
The transaction simulation failed with the above error.

Here is the simplified version of my code:
import {
  ALL_PROGRAM_ID,
  API_URLS,
  ApiSwapV1Out,
  getATAAddress,
  swapBaseInAutoAccount
} from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2';
import { NATIVE_MINT, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connection, owner } from '../config';

const TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS = "BfuPnXM7Qs46ZLuptSAHhmnoZ7sa8cpnfJnhTj81fKTg";

export const apiSwap = async () => {
  try {
    const inputMint = NATIVE_MINT.toBase58();
    const outputMint = TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS;

    const amount = 10000000; // 0.01 SOL in Lamports
    const slippage = 0.5;
    const txVersion: 'LEGACY' | 'VO' = 'LEGACY';

    const { data: swapResponse } = await axios.get<ApiSwapV1Out>(`${API_URLS.SWAP_HOST}/compute/swap-base-out?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${outputMint}&amount=${amount}&slippageBps=${slippage * 100}&txVersion=${txVersion}`);
    const res = await axios.get(API_URLS.BASE_HOST + API_URLS.POOL_KEY_BY_ID + `?ids=${swapResponse.data.routePlan.map((r) => r.poolId).join(',')}`);

    const inputAccount = (await getATAAddress(owner.publicKey, new PublicKey(inputMint), TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID)).publicKey;

// I created the output ata manually with solana spl-token cli 
    const outputAccount = new PublicKey("7TMMYtCcT4qSrfFZWfC2G7CQZ9Q5a1XxZNsvuNk7TESD");

    const tx = new Transaction();

    const ins = swapBaseInAutoAccount({
      programId: ALL_PROGRAM_ID.Router,
      wallet: owner.publicKey,
      amount: new BN(amount),
      inputAccount,
      outputAccount,
      routeInfo: swapResponse,
      poolKeys: res.data.data,
    });

    let { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized');
    tx.add(ins);
    tx.feePayer = owner.publicKey;
    tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

    tx.sign(owner);

    const signature = await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [owner], { skipPreflight: false, preflightCommitment: 'finalized' });
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature, blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }, 'finalized');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error executing the swap:', error);
  }
};

apiSwap();

Error Details:
Error Type: SendTransactionError
Simulation Failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x26
Program log: Error: InvalidSplTokenProgram
I’ve checked the inputs, including the mint addresses, input and output accounts, and the swap service response. Everything seems correct.
What I’ve Tried:
I verified that the mint addresses are valid for the token program.
I confirmed that the token accounts are created for the correct mint types.
I checked if the associated token accounts (ATAs) for the input and output tokens were correct.
Questions:
What does the InvalidSplTokenProgram error mean, and how can I resolve it?
Could it be an issue with the token program version or a configuration mismatch?
Is there any missing step or configuration that I am overlooking for this swap transaction to work?

try to use TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID instead of TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, from what i see your token attached to the old one
https://solscan.io/token/BfuPnXM7Qs46ZLuptSAHhmnoZ7sa8cpnfJnhTj81fKTg

